# How set in value type int?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need set value int. how do this?

```
    var list = from Enum e in Enum.GetValues(enumValue.GetType())
           select new SelectListItem
           {
               Selected = e.Equals(enumValue),
               Text = e.ToDescription(),
               Value = e.ToString()// need int
           };
```

if I set `Value = ((int)e).ToString()`

I get error:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Enum' to 'int'

Comment: `((int)e).ToString()` try this

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK in C#, Enums can be convert to int:

```
 Value = ((int)e).ToString()
```

That is as long as the underlying type is an int or castable to an int.

Comment: That is as long as the underlying type is an `int` or castable to an `int`.

Comment: Don't forget that `SelectListitem.Value` is a `string`.

Answer (score 2):

Cast to an `int` and get a string from it:

```
Value = ((int)e).ToString()
```

All enumerations are based on integer types, so a cast is the simplest solution (though if the enum is based on a `long`, you may get an overflow).

Additionally, the type returned from `Enum.GetValues` is the values of the enumeration - your LINQ should be:

```
from e in Enum.GetValues(enumValue.GetType())
```

As `e` will *not* be of type `Enum`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
(int)YourEnum.enumValue;
```

or

```
(int)e
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var list = from Enum e in Enum.GetValues(enumValue.GetType())
       select new SelectListItem
       {
           Selected = e.Equals(enumValue),
           Text = e.ToDescription(),
           Value = (int) e
       };
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert enum directly by casting it to int type.